# send sms through kannel using the fake SMS center

Tags: sms, kannel

I configured kannel as fake SMS center. But when I try to send sms, I get the following error:

```
2010-02-24 15:12:30 [932] [12] DEBUG: send_msg: sending msg to box: 
2010-02-24 15:12:30 [932] [12] ERROR: Error writing 16 octets to fd 34:
2010-02-24 15:12:30 [932] [12] ERROR: System error 104: Connection reset by peer
2010-02-24 15:12:30 [932] [12] ERROR: Couldn't write Msg to box , disconnecting
2010-02-24 15:12:30 [932] [12] DEBUG: Thread 12 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender) terminates.
2010-02-24 15:12:30 [932] [11] ERROR: Error writing 16 octets to fd 34:
2010-02-24 15:12:30 [932] [11] ERROR: System error 104: Connection reset by peer
2010-02-24 15:12:30 [932] [11] DEBUG: Thread 11 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function) terminates.
2010-02-24 15:12:35 [932] [15] ERROR: Error reading from fd 39:
2010-02-24 15:12:35 [932] [15] ERROR: System error 104: Connection reset by peer
2010-02-24 15:12:35 [932] [15] ERROR: Error reading from fd 39:
2010-02-24 15:12:35 [932] [15] ERROR: System error 104: Connection reset by peer
```

What's wrong?

Url for send sms:

```
http://localhost:13003/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=&password=&to=0123456&text=Hello+world
```

I ran kannel under cygwin and red hat, on each system error is the same.

My kannel.conf

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = bar
log-file = /var/log/kannel/kannel.log
log-level = 0
access-log = /var/log/kannel/access_kannel.log
store-file = /var/log/kannel/store_sms

group = smsc
smsc = fake
port = 13004
connect-allow-ip = "*.*.*.*"

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 13003
global-sender = 13003
smsbox-id = "my smsbox"
log-file = /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
log-level = 0

group = sendsms-user
username = 
password = 

group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No service specified"
```

Comment: Can you post more logs form bearerbox startup. there is not any relevant information form log you have given. What UR you are using to send messages, and logs at SMS box?

Comment: URL for send messages:

http://localhost:13001/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=&password=&to=0123456&text=Hello+world

logs added

Comment: Helpa, Please change your port form 13001 to 13003. But without detailed logs you can't get a detailed information this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Port in url was wrong.

Comment: Does not seem programming related.  Voting to move to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when peer closes the connection (while kannel is still trying to read or send the message), and so kannel only shows this to you in the log trail.

The issue is not with kannel but with the peer.

Find out why the connection is closed by the peer.
If the connection is not closed, then this error should not happen and kannel should be able to read/send the message.

Thanks.